# adding multiple animations to the nonlinear animation section? (with a single command or button)

Tags: animation

I have 80 animations. It is very tedious to transfer these animations to the nonlinear animation section by clicking the stash button one by one. How do I transfer all animations to the nonlinear animation section by clicking a single button?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In the NLA window, *Menu > Add > Add action* (shortcut <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: That method doesn't seem to allow multiple actions to be added as strips all at once, which is what the OP wants to know how to do.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without Pythoon scripting.

Comment: Maybe you should remove your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, what i want is not to add animations one by one but add them all. I want to add all animations with one click.